# Not able to create hyperledger fabric network using cello

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-cello

I started cello and i am able to open user dashboard on 8081 but not the operator dashboard (I checked the port and found docker-proxy named service is running). Now on user dashboard i am trying to create a new network. But it's throwing error **Apply Chain myorg fail**. I have attached the screenshot. [image]. I checked the post request reponse and it shows `{"success":false,"message":"System maintenance, please try again later!"}`

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue? because I've been struggling with it a week already

Answer (score -1):

The Cello system is suggested to be deployed on multiple servers, at least 1 Master Node + 1 Worker Node.

- Make sure that you have done installation of worker

  http://hyperledger-cello.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_worker_docker/
- Then make sure you added worker hosts in operator dashboard and chains are active.

  http://localhost:8080/view/hosts (Add hosts)

  http://localhost:8080/view/clusters?type=active (Check chains active or not)

For more information on cello installation refer: [Hyperledger Cello Installation](https://medium.com/@pvrforpranavvr/hyperledger-cello-setup-f31954a9551f)